# how to setState & display multiple selected images from gallery in a view

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native.I had used npm react-native-image-crop-picker for accessing gallery & camera.I am only able to access either gallery or camera at a time.How do I access them both at the same time and how would I display multiple selected images in a view?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks, in advance.My sample code,

```
galleryAccessFunc() {
        ImagePicker.openPicker({
            multiple: true
          }).then(image => {
            console.log(image)
            this.setState({ImageSource:image.path})
          });debugger
    }
```

when I try to display the selected images it returns an empty view,

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.galleryAccessFunc.bind(this)} >
          <View style={styles.ImageContainer}>
          { this.state.ImageSource === null ? <Text>Select a Photo</Text> :
              <Image style={styles.ImageContainer} source={ this.state.ImageSource} />
            }
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

and how do I access both gallery & camera at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pickMultiple() {
        ImagePicker.openPicker({
  multiple: true,
  waitAnimationEnd: false
}).then(images => {
  this.setState({
    image: null,
    images: images.map(i => {
      console.log('received image', i);
      return {uri: i.path, width: i.width, height: i.height, mime: i.mime};
    })

  });
 }).catch(e => alert(e));
 }
```

and view like this

```
<ScrollView horizontal >
     this.state.images.map((i,key) => <View key={i.uri}>{this.renderAsset(i,key)} 
</View>) : 
  </ScrollView>
```

if you want pick from both gallery and camera, 
Then create a button and show an option like from gallery or camera and call different function to take images